# how to change format date in node.js

Tags: node.js, web, date-formatting

im newbie in node js, i create a web use node js, i show date from database, but i want to change the format date

```
this.editNewEvent = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    // var start_date = ;
    var dateFormat = require('dateFormat');
    // var day_start = dateFormat(start_date, "dd/mm/yyyy");
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        if (err) throw err;
        con.query('SELECT id, event_code, event_name, id_type, event_category, description, start_date, end_date, location_name, longitude, latitude FROM transaksi_new_events WHERE id = "' + id + '" order by modified_at desc', function(err, rows) {
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
                res.render('transaksi_new_event/edit', { obj: obj });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

in my web the date show '2018-03-01T17:00:00.000Z' i want change format to dd/mm/yyyy

[my web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DifYd.png)

Comment: You can use momentjs for easy formatting and manipulation of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

take a look from here [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
from that u can use built in date class in js create your own function that return new date format or u can search existing library out there

```
new Date('2018-03-01T17:00:00.000Z') with getMonth(), getFullYear(),  and getDate()
```

Also you can use moment npm for it.Moment was designed to work both in the browser and in Node.js.

Comment: jquery is javascript and that absolutly can